# Continuing with zero filters at Polis

Tags: metro-2033

I have come back to Metro 2033 for a ranger easy play-through and have reached Polis with zero filters for my gas mask, and to my surprise they are not available at polis. Obviously I could go back to the last place where they are sold, but that is prohibitively far.

Does anyone have any game-play ideas for continuing with zero filters?
Otherwise does anyone know any good ways to mod the gamesave to produce more filters? I have the tool "360revolution" that offers the ability to mod saves to "god mode" and "infinite ammo", but even if these work it sounds to me like cracking a nut with a sledgehammer.

Comment: A bit specific so I'm not holding my breath (...sorry). Isn't the move away from cheats and customizability with these consoles tiresome?

Comment: do you have absolutely 0 or close to it?  There's a way to 'cheat' the system by putting on and removing the filter quickly without using it up.

Comment: I can go back a level and have a few filters, go the main way through black station and try that. I understand Artyom lasts 30sec without one, I'll have to see how far I can get (It has to be far enough to fall through the elevator?). In that case, I hope there are filters at Sparta Base.

Comment: I went back to the surface section before black station, and using the tactics you mentioned manages to save 11 filters. Thanks.

Comment: awesome.  its lame but its the only way i was able to preserve enough filters to beat ranger easy (not even gonna attempt ranger hardcore)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As soon as you leave the station, turn left (don't go into the ditch), there's a dead body there from which you can collect some filters.

[image]

I found this info in [this](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=1646002) thread

Comment: I was SEVERELY annoyed with having to go outside with 1 filter at ~:01. When dude said I had to go outside to the library, I just threw my hands up and started looking for a cheat. it took about :15 to find this tidbit. Thanks.